# Bootstrap thumbnail grid gallery correction

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap image gallery is not correctly.

Here you can see its too much space there. My images are not everytime same size:

**Wrong**

[image]

I photoshopped what it should look like:

**Correct**

[image]

My code:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="container">     
        <?php while($gallery = mysqli_fetch_array($db)) {
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <figure class="effect-marley">
                <a title="<?php echo $gallery['gallery_thumbnail']; ?>" data-lightbox="gallery-popup" href="<?php echo $CONF['installation_path'] . $gallery['gallery_thumbnail']; ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $CONF['installation_path'] . 'system/timthumb.php?src=' . $CONF['installation_path'] . $gallery['gallery_thumbnail'] . '&h=350&zc=1'; ?>" alt="<?php echo $gallery['gallery_name']; ?>" />
                </a>
                <figcaption>
                    <p><?php echo $gallery['gallery_name']; ?></p>              
                </figcaption>           
            </figure>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont think bootstrap works that way. check out this plugin instead - http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Rows are 100% width in Bootstrap. To do what you want, you would have to use some sort of masonry grid framework like Ionic.

Comment: Got working it :) Thanks guys :)